# Swift: Define relationships between classes

Tags: swift, class, relationships

I'm trying to figure out how to setup the relationship between two classes so that I'm able to determine the properties of one by knowing the other.

Let's say I have Owner and Pet, where the owner has a pet.

```
class Owner{
    let name: String
    var age: Int
    let petName: String

    init(name: String, age: Int, petName: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.petName = petName
    }
}

class Pet{
    let petName: String
    var age: Int
    let petType: String

    init(petName: String, age: Int, petType: String) {
        self.petName = petName
        self.age = age
        self.petType = petType
        }    
    }
```

Assuming each petName is unique, I'd like to be able to do something like owner.petType where I can return the petType for the petName of the owner. Is this possible? Should I set the classes up differently?

Comment: `Owner` should not have a `petName` property. It should have an `pets` property which is an array of `Pet`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set up your classes as such:

```
class Owner {
    let name: String
    var age: Int
    var pet: Pet? //Owner might not have a pet - thus optional or can also have an array of pets

    init(name: String, age: Int, pet: Pet) {
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.pet = pet
    }
}

class Pet {
    let name: String
    var age: Int
    let type: String

    init(name: String, age: Int, type: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.type = type
    }    
}
```

Comment: Might be worth considering if `pet` ivar in `Owner` class needs to be weak. Also `Owner` could have more than 1 pet. So should it be `pets`?. Depends on your business logic. Similarly `Pet` could have a weak ivar for `owner`

Comment: As you see in my example above, the class Pet doesn't have a reference to its owner. Hence it's not necessary to mark pet(s) as a weak reference.